# SQL. Одинаковые результаты для IN и NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Объясните мне дураку, какого Шредингера тут происходит.

```
SELECT num, 
CASE 
    WHEN num NOT IN (SELECT P FROM BST) THEN 'NOT in P'
    WHEN num IN (SELECT P FROM BST) THEN 'in P'
    WHEN num NOT IN (SELECT N FROM BST) THEN 'NOT in N'
    WHEN num IN (SELECT N FROM BST) THEN 'in N'
    ELSE 'lalala'
END
FROM (
    SELECT num
    FROM(
        (SELECT DISTINCT N as num FROM BST)
        UNION
        (SELECT DISTINCT P as num FROM BST)
        )    as nums
    WHERE num is not NULL
    ORDER BY num ASC
    ) as tab1
LIMIT 1;
```

Вывод:

```
1 in N
```

Если написать через конструкцию if для каждого из возможных вариантов, то он пишет мне:

```
1 in P NOT in P In N In N
```

Получается что элемент одновременно *находится в P* и *не находится в P*.

Что я делаю не так?

P.S.
Таблица **BST** содержит:

```
N | Integer
P | Integer
```

Таблица-подзапрос в FROM содержит неповторяющиеся элементы из обоих столбцах таблицы BST

Пытаюсь решить так

Comment: Создайте fiddle с указанными структурой, (непоказанным) наполнением и запросом. А то пока неясно, в чём проблема...